# Issue using Sqoop to import data from Sybase

Tags: database, jdbc, hadoop, sybase, sqoop

I am trying to import data from Sybase using Sqoop. From logs i can say that i have mangeged to do a coonection successfully.
But my job fails giving me some Sql exception from Sybase. I don't primarily work on Sybase so 
could not dig out much with this error. Only one of my sources resides at Sybase.

I used following command:

```
sqoop import --verbose \
--driver com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver \
--connect jdbc:sybase:Tds:nyhostx123.sm.com:13290/DATABASE=tempdb \
--table tempdb..mit \
--split-by sipid \
--fields-terminated-by ',' \
--target-dir /home/DEVTEST/sqoop_mit \
--username user01 \
-m 1 \
-P
```

**Error Snippet:**

```
13/03/14 07:36:19 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201301151126_25936
13/03/14 07:36:20 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/03/14 07:36:27 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201301151126_25936_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.db.DBRecordReader.nextKeyValue(DBRecordReader.java:265)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.nextKeyValue(MapTask.java:456)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.MapContext.nextKeyValue(MapContext.java:67)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:143)
        at org.apache.sqoop.mapreduce.AutoProgressMapper.run(AutoProgressMapper.java:182)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:647)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:323)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:266)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1278)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:260)
Caused by: com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybSQLException: Incorrect syntax near '.'.

        at com.sybase.jdbc3.tds.Tds.a(Unknown Source)
        at
attempt_201301151126_25936_m_000000_0: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient).
attempt_201301151126_25936_m_000000_0: log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
13/03/14 07:36:33 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201301151126_25936_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
java.io.IOException: SQLException in nextKeyValue
```

Comment: Is this for Sybase ASA/SQLAnywhere or ASE? What version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the problem is in --table parameter. Sqoop is expecting pure table name, but you seem to be passing extra value "tempdb.." (I guess it's a db name?). Would you mind trying it out with "--table mit" only?

Comment: I tried this option too. (--table mit). But, then Sqoop didn't recognize the table. I got this error message "mit not found. Specify owner.objectname or use sp_help to check whether the object exists (sp_help may produce lots of output)."

Comment: What happens when you log into the database, and manually issue the "sp_help mit" in the tempdb database?

Comment: sqoop import --verbose
--driver com.sybase.jdbc3.jdbc.SybDriver
--connect jdbc:sybase:ddd:ny0xxwxx.rr.com:13290/doy/interfaces
--query "select * from tempdb..dd_indic where \$CONDITIONS" --fields-terminated-by ','
--target-dir /TTS/DEVTEST/try_indic --username muniretail -m 1 -P                                                                   I was telling the wrong db. Rest all is fine.